# get all characters before selected keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to get all the characters before the selected keyword

Ex:

```
const str = "This is example sentence for this stack overflow question"
const searchTerm =  "stack"
```

What is required

```
expected results = 'for this stack overflow question'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string and then search for index of the search item. If index is not equal to -1 than simply perform join operation on the array.
try the following. Furthermore, you can use `replace()` to replace the search term if they are separated by whitespace.

```js
const str = "This is example sentence for this stack overflow question"
const searchTerm =  "stack overflow";

var strReplace = str.replace(searchTerm, '&&');
var strArray = strReplace.split(" ");
var index = strArray.indexOf('&&');
if(index != -1){
  index = index -2 >= 0 ? index -2 : index;
  var result = strArray.slice(index).join(" ").replace('&&', searchTerm);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: works fine with single word.. but when we add two words with space for search term.. then not working mate..

Comment: @lpradhap use `replace()` first. Check the updated code and let me now if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str = "This is example sentence for this stack overflow question"
const searchTerm =  "stack"

const strings = str.split(" ");
// if you are very sure the str `must` contains searchTerm
const idx = strings.findIndex(item => item==searchTerm);
// if you are very sure the idx `must` greater than 2
console.log(strings.slice(idx-2).join(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array `spilt()`, `slice()` and `join()` methods to achieve this:

```js
let str = "This is example sentence for this stack overflow question";
let searchTerm =  "stack"
function getSubstring(str){
  var arrStr = str.split(' ');
  var termIndex = arrStr.indexOf(searchTerm);
  var res;
  if(termIndex-2 > -1){
    res = arrStr.slice(termIndex-2).join(' ');
  } else {
    res = arrStr.slice(termIndex).join(' ');
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(getSubstring(str));
str = "stack overflow question"
console.log(getSubstring(str));
```

Comment: works fine with single word.. but when we add two words with space for search term.. then not working mate..

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```js
const str = "This is example sentence for this stack overflow question"
const searchTerm =  "stack";
var strArray = str.split(" ");
var searchTermIndex = strArray.indexOf(searchTerm);
if(searchTermIndex-2 > -1){
var result= strArray.slice(searchTermIndex-2).join(" ");
 console.log(result);
   }
```

Comment: works fine with single word.. but when we add two words with space for search term.. then not working mate..

Comment: ye.it will not work because we are splitting the str with space.May be your problem is different